# PHPMailer Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: php, smtp, wamp, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer on a Wampserver PHP-based system.

The emailing had been working perfectly until we switched to a 4G connection at work.

Now I'm getting this error:

> 2020-10-01 05:39:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

> 2020-10-01 05:39:25 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: The specified procedure could not be found. [C:\Users_\phpMailer\src\SMTP.php line 458]

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

It's pointing to  the below section in the SMTP.php file:

```
public function startTLS()
{
    if (!$this->sendCommand('STARTTLS', 'STARTTLS', 220)) {
        return false;
    }

    //Allow the best TLS version(s) we can
    $crypto_method = STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT;

    //PHP 5.6.7 dropped inclusion of TLS 1.1 and 1.2 in STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
    //so add them back in manually if we can
    if (defined('STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT')) {
        $crypto_method |= STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT;
        $crypto_method |= STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_1_CLIENT;
    }
    // Begin encrypted connection
    set_error_handler([$this, 'errorHandler']);
     $crypto_ok = stream_socket_enable_crypto(
        $this->smtp_conn,
        true,
        $crypto_method
    ); 
    restore_error_handler();

    return (bool) $crypto_ok;
}
```

I was forced to move the email port to 587 in Outlook on the computers here and a TLS encryption.

I really need this to work as it's sending confirmation emails to my boss for all orders put into the system.

Comment: What do you see if you set `SMTPDebug=4`?

Comment: @Synchro edited

Comment: How about you add it to your question so we have something to go on?

Comment: @Synchro I've tried to add it but it won't allow me to post the data dump.

Comment: @Synchro added the DEBUG lines

Comment: This sounds like you either don't have openssl installed, or perhaps have a very old version. What PHP version are you using? What does your PHP installation say in `phpinfo()` about openssl?

Comment: @Synchro PHP Version 5.5.12, OpenSSL Version 1.0.1g

Comment: Ick. Upgrade. There is no reason to run such an ancient version of PHP. It's been out of support for years, is a security risk, and is likely to contain bugs like this.

Comment: @Synchro I need to upgrade Wampserver to upgrade the PHP version, but I will look into that. Thanks for your help.